# Stanford Parser: how to extract dependencies?

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp

My work consists in finding a query (can be `noun+verb`) in a sentence, then extract the object.

exemple: `"coding is sometimes a tough work."` My query would be: `"coding is"`.

the typed dependencies i get are:

```
nsubj(work-6, coding-1)   
cop(work-6, is-2)    
advmod(work-6, sometimes-3)
det(work-6, a-4)
amod(work-6, tough-5)
```

My program should extract the nsubj dependency, identify `"coding"` as the query and save `"work"`.

May be this seems simple, but until now, i didn't find a method able to extract a specific typed dependency, and I really need this to finish my work.

Any help is welcome,

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: I am using java, but for this old comment i find the solution, i used StringTokonizer 2 times, with "(" as separator, then wit ",". Finally i put the extracted tokens in an xml file.

Answer (score 10):

**You can find dependencies by following code:**

```java
Tree tree = sentence.get(TreeAnnotation.class);
// Get dependency tree
TreebankLanguagePack tlp = new PennTreebankLanguagePack();
GrammaticalStructureFactory gsf = tlp.grammaticalStructureFactory();
GrammaticalStructure gs = gsf.newGrammaticalStructure(tree);
Collection<TypedDependency> td = gs.typedDependenciesCollapsed();
System.out.println(td);

Object[] list = td.toArray();
System.out.println(list.length);
TypedDependency typedDependency;
for (Object object : list) {
typedDependency = (TypedDependency) object;
System.out.println("Depdency Name"typedDependency.dep().nodeString()+ " :: "+ "Node"+typedDependency.reln());
if (typedDependency.reln().getShortName().equals("something")) {
   //your code
}
```

Comment: The code is in Java, and its well addressed the problem in domain of NLP specifically to Stanford Core NLP API.
@Alain is it not make sense to address the problems ??

Comment: That's fine, but generally the answers accepted and up-voted on SO involve just a little more context than a block of code, even if the code is fairly straightforward. Perhaps by adapting your sample use case to solve the original question? Either way, I'm afraid you won't get much more feedback from the author since the question hasn't had any activity in 2 years.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to tell the parser to extract the dependencies around a given word. However, you can just run through the list of dependencies for each sentence, searching for all instances in which the query word appears in an `nsubj` relationship.

Also, how are you storing the parses of the sentences? If (as I gather from your question) it's in a text file, you can just use 2 successive greps, one for the query word, and one for the relationship you desire, to get a list of relevant other words.